# Android Contacs not shown im ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, contacts

i want to show a simple list of the Contacs in my App. The example code from google is very large and complex, so i searched for other examples.. I found this one:

```
import android.content.*;
import android.database.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.provider.*;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.support.v4.content.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
        private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // create adapter once
                Context context = getActivity();
                int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
                Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
                int flags = 0; // no auto-requery! Loader requeries.
                mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); // each time we are started use our listadapter
                setListAdapter(mAdapter); // and tell loader manager to start loading
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        // columns requested from the database
        private static final String[] PROJECTION =
        {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,// _ID is always required
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, // that's what we want to display
        };

        // and name should be displayed in the text1 textview in item layout
        private static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
        private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
        {
                // load from the "Contacts table"
                Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI; // no sub-selection, no sort order, simply every row // projection says we want just the _id and the name column
                return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), contentUri, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
        {
                // Once cursor is loaded, give it to adapter
                mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
        {
                // on reset take any old cursor away
                mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
        }

}
```

(Thanks to zapl)

With this listview:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

My problem is very simple: The listview is empty! Did i do sth. wrong in the xml? Or whats missing?

Thank you in advance.

Mfg
Lolxdfly

==========EDIT===========
I am new to Java.. Do i have to call the Activity in my MainActivity? :S maybe thats the mistake..
I have tried the following:

```
ContactsFragment fragment = new ContactsFragment ();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

That makes my application crash:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: What about your Java source code that controls the activity? What does your Adapter look like. That is more likely to be the problem than the  XML. By the way, post your code directly because links can be broken.

Comment: I am sorry for the links, but i am writing from my phone.. i cant press CTRL+K and i cant use the editor.... :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set add onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_own_custon_layout, container, false);
return view;
}
```

After that change id in your layout to `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: I added this method in my ContactsFragment class, but that dont fixed it.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change ListView's id in fragment's layout.
I copied all your code and all worked fine with these changes.
See how to use fragments here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html